# Laravel Storage method allDirectories() does not return recursively directories from FTP server

Tags: laravel, ftp

I need to get list of all directories from the FTP server.

After successful FTP driver setup, `Storage::allDirectories()` method is returning all directories from root directory. I have also tried to use:

`Storage::directories('/', true)`

Which should also return recursive values but it's the same case.

Does anyone have any idea what should be problem?

This is my FTP connection setup:

```
$ftp = Storage::createFtpDriver([
   'host' => $streamServer->url,
   'username' => $streamServer->username,
   'password' => $streamServer->password,
   'port' => '21',
   'timeout' => '30',
]);
```

Comment: you will have to iterate over the directories list recursively yourself,

Comment: That's what I am doing at the moment but I was hoping to find optimal solution. But thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow

I have checked with my code and it's working when I added the following line in my `filesystems.php`

I have created ftp driver in `filesystems` as below.

```
'ftp' => [
        'driver' => env('DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_DRIVER','sftp'),
        'host' => env('DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_HOST','127.0.0.1'),
        'username' => env('DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_USERNAME','root'),
        'password' => env('DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_PASSWORD','root'),
        'root'=> env('DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_ROOT', '/var/www/html')
        'port'     => env('DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_PORT', 22),
        'timeout'  => env('DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_TIMEOUT', 30),
    ],
```

this line is additionaly added.

```
'root'=> env('DOCUMENT_UPLOAD_ROOT', '/var/www/html')
```

and when I use the following command it works for me.

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->allDirectories('directoryName');
```

provide directory name from which you want to get list or leave blank will provide you the list of all the recursive directories from `html` directory because we have provided it as a root.

after that you need to extract directories manually, as it just gives you an array like `namespace` will all the recursive directories.

Comment: The thing is that users have to add ftp parameters by themselves so I have to setup connection in Controller.

But I have now tried with another FTP server and allDirectories() method worked fine... Seems like it has to do something with FTP server but I am not sure what could that be.

Edit:
Difference between old and new FTP is that the old one has more that 2000 directories only in root, and the new FTP where recursion worked, has only 100 directories. 
Perhaps there is some problem with number of directories.